# Hibernate - Skip Envers historisation for specific action or a transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, history, hibernate-envers

We are currently using Envers to do Historisation. Sometimes we have to create temporary copies of certain data or simply don't want certain things to end up in history. Currently, we have a really ugly solution. That solution is a global boolean, which doesn't guarantee thread-safety and might cause certain data that should've been historised to not be historised or the other way around.

I was wondering if there's any good solution to this. I assume one way might be to use the `EnversPost*EventListener`s and flag every bean that should be ignored once. However, while this sounds less terrible, I fear it might still not end up well, since I am not quite sure what the object lifecycle in Hibernate looks like and whether this could cause false-negatives.

Anyway, to me it looks like there should be some better built-in solution to this problem, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're describing is called conditional auditing.

The only way to do this currently is to extend the existing Hibernate Envers listeners and add any logic where you need to skip creating audit entity rows based on the entity's current state.  You'll find quite a number of listeners in `org.hibernate.envers.event.spi` to cover all the necessary lifecycle callbacks not only for entities but also for collections associated with entities.

Generally speaking, the `post` events are the ones of importance here.  There are a few `pre-collection` and `pre-update` event listeners but the only one which may need some extending could be the ones related to collections depending on your entity mappings used.

After you've extended the necessary listeners, you'll need to configure Envers not to register its own listeners by setting `hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners=false`.

You'll also need to introduce a custom `Integrator` implementation that performs the registration of your extended listeners.  You can see the code inside `org.hibernate.envers.EnversIntegrator` for all the pertinent details of how to do this.  These integrators are detected using the Java Service API, so you'll also need to add a `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` file to your classpath which lists your custom integrator so it can be found.

Comment: I see, that's kind of what I was trying to avoid, as it's already the solution we got. I'll just have to improve our existing solution then.